# Reverse SelectionSort to sort array

Tags: java, arrays, algorithm, selection-sort

My selection sort here runs through the remaining part of the array, looking for the minimum value and then swaps it to the front.I want to change the algorithm so that it also looks for the maximum value in the remaining part, and swaps it to the back, so that it builds up a sorted list from the front and the back at the same time.

```
public  void selectionSort(String[ ] data){
    // for each position, from 0 up, find the next smallest item 
    // and swap it into place
    for (int place=0; place<data.length-1; place++){
        int minIndex = place;
        for (int sweep=place+1; sweep<data.length; sweep++){
            if (data[sweep].compareTo(data[minIndex]) < 0)
                minIndex=sweep;
        }
        swap(data, place, minIndex);
    }
}
```

I have another method that checks if the array has been sorted or not so the solution has to go through that

```
public boolean testSorted(String[] data) {
    for (int i=1; i<data.length; i++){
        if (data[i].compareTo(data[i-1]) < 0)
            return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

Any help would be appreciated, I've been going at it for hours. I'm new to this and I really wanna get it. Thanks

This is what I have tried:

```
public  void selectionSort2(String[ ] data){
    // for each position, from 0 up, find the next smallest item 
    // and swap it into place
    for (int place=0; place<data.length-1; place++){
        int minIndex = place;
        for (int sweep=place+1; sweep<data.length; sweep++){
            if (data[sweep].compareTo(data[minIndex]) > 0)
                minIndex=sweep;
        }
        swap(data, place, minIndex);
    }
}
```

Comment: What about reversing the result?
`java.util.Arrays.reverse(array);`

Comment: Show us what you have tried. I see no attempt to code it yourself.

Comment: That's pretty much a bubble sort...but why are you trying to optimize this in the first place?  Certainly for the small, O(n^2) algorithms, the less complexity the better.

Comment: @Andreas I have put what I've tried up there

Comment: @LouisWasserman It's just I'm trying to learn how to do this so I can test them and compare performance for assignment. I'm new to this so I'm trying to see if what I did was correct etc

Comment: How does simply flipping `<` to `>` make the code do *both* minimum to front *and* maximum to back, at the *same* time? You changed **1** character, how is that an attempt to double the action?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You only need to change and it will sort in reverse orger:

In method `selectionSort()`

```
if (data[sweep].compareTo(data[minIndex]) > 0)
```

and in method `testSorted()`

```
if (data[i].compareTo(data[i-1]) > 0)
```

But if you need to change order, so that it must start sort from back of array, it will look as:

```
    public static void selectionSort(String[ ] data){
    // for each position, from 0 up, find the next smallest item
    // and swap it into place
    for(int place=data.length-1; place >= 1; place--){
        int maxIndex= place;
        for(int sweep = place-1; sweep >= 0; sweep--){
            if(data[sweep].compareTo(data[maxIndex]) > 0){
                maxIndex = sweep;
            }
        }
        swap(data, place, maxIndex);
    }
```

Comment: Alright sweet as thank you. I was just wondering if what I did was correct.

Comment: This answer reverses the sort order, but that is **not** what the question was asking for. The question stated that original code moved minimum to front, and was asking to *also* move maximum to back. Move min → front and/or max → back, doesn't change order.